# Scraping TripAdvisor link with Google Sheets' importxml function not working

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to scrape a link from TripAdvisor using the importxml function in google sheets. Here is an example:

http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g34127-d491231-Reviews-Celebration_Town_Tavern-Celebration_Florida.html

The link is the "Great Vibe, Great Food” title it is:

/ShowUserReviews-g34127-d491231-r257722735-Celebration_Town_Tavern-Celebration_Florida.html#REVIEWS"

The challenge is that I would like to pull the similar links from multiple TripAdvisor pages (just the latest review) and the id within the  tag changes.

I have tried using the XPATH

```
"//*[@class='wrap']/@href"
```

This is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to add sample HTML snippets for various pages you want to scrape properly.

Comment: You're going to have to give us some examples of the inputs, the expected output, and the actual output, _in the question itself_.  "This is not working" is not enough information for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed a bit of the source:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="quote isNew">
    <a href="/ShowUserReviews-g34127-d491231-r257722735-Celebration_Town_Tavern-Celebration_Florida.html#REVIEWS" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('Reviews','title','',0,this.href); ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie('4442')" id="rn257722735">&#x201c;<span class='noQuotes'>Great Vibe, Great Food</span>&#x201d;</a>
  </div>
```

You tried `//*[@class='wrap']/@href` which says "find any element with a class attribute = 'wrap', and give me that element's href attribute's value".  It finds `<div class="wrap">` which has no href attribute.

You need to find the anchor (element `<a>`) and get its href. Since there is another div level, you need something like:

```
//div[@class='wrap']/div[@class='quote isNew']/a/@href
```

I'll leave it to you to analyze the input source for the specific rules you need.  The important part is to end up selecting the `<a>` element and getting the @href from there.